# java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: socket write error

Tags: java, networking, java-me

I am trying to send an image from a Java desktop application to a J2ME application. The problem is that I am getting this exception:

```
java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: socket write error
```

I have looked around on the net, and although this problem is not that rare, I was unable to find a concrete solution. I am transforming the image into a byte array before transferring it. These are the methods found on the desktop application and on the J2ME respectively

```
    public void send(String ID, byte[] serverMessage) throws Exception
    {            
        //Get the IP and Port of the person to which the message is to be sent.
        String[] connectionDetails = this.userDetails.get(ID).split(",");
        Socket sock = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName(connectionDetails[0]), Integer.parseInt(connectionDetails[1]));
        OutputStream os = sock.getOutputStream();
        for (int i = 0; i < serverMessage.length; i++)
        {
            os.write((int) serverMessage[i]);
        }
        os.flush();
        os.close();
        sock.close();
    }

    private void read(final StreamConnection slaveSock)
    {
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                try
                {
                    DataInputStream dataInputStream = slaveSock.openDataInputStream();
                    int inputChar;
                    StringBuffer results = new StringBuffer();
                    while ( (inputChar = dataInputStream.read()) != -1)
                    {
                        results.append((char) inputChar);
                    }
                    dataInputStream.close();
                    slaveSock.close();
                    parseMessage(results.toString());
                    results = null;
                }

                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Alert alertMsg = new Alert("Error", "An error has occured while reading a message from the server:\n" + e.getMessage(), null, AlertType.ERROR);
                    alertMsg.setTimeout(Alert.FOREVER);
                    myDisplay.setCurrent(alertMsg, resultScreen);
                }
            }
        };
        new Thread(runnable).start();
    }
```

I am sending the message across a LAN, and I have no problems when I send short text messages instead of images. Also, I used wireshark and it seems that the desktop application is only sending part of the message. Any help would be highly appreciated. Also, everything works on the J2ME simulator.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please refer to the answers to [Official reasons for "Software caused connection abort: socket write error"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2126607/official-reasons-for-software-caused-connection-abort-socket-write-error)

**EDIT**

I don't think there is much more that can be said in general, and there doesn't appear to be anything unusual about your code that would cause connections to abort.  I would however note that:

- Casting the bytes to integers for the `write` call is unnecessary.  It will be promoted automatically.
- It would be better (simpler, potentially more efficient in terms of network traffic) to use `write(byte[])` instead of `write(int)`.
- The receiving side is assuming that each byte represents a complete character.  This may be incorrect depending on how the sending side formed the bytes to be transmitted, and
- It would be a good idea to start by sending a byte count so that the receiving end can tell if something has gone wrong before the sender sent the whole byte array.

Comment: I had already gone through those answers. I looked at the windows event log, I did not see anything relevant, event though I am not that experienced at going through these logs.
Secondly, I also tried adding in the shutdownOutput(); but still no avail.
Lastly, I get an error from the J2ME application saying that the socket was closed.

Comment: Well... I do not know how but I seem to can get it working now. I tried replacing the casting to integer part, but that totally broke down my application, disabling it completely. I tried sending it today and it worked. My guess is that it was some external cause, probably the router restarted or something else.