# java DataOutputStream exception

Tags: java, exception, dataoutputstream

The exception is thrown in line 24 the second time I type something (after I have typed the host name) - server works right. Code

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

class TCPclient {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String hostname, msg;
        InetAddress hostaddress;
        BufferedReader inFromUser = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.println("Please type host\n");
        hostname = inFromUser.readLine();   //I type localhost
        hostaddress = InetAddress.getByName(hostname);
        Socket cSocket = new Socket(hostaddress, 44444);
        String cAddress = cSocket.getLocalSocketAddress().toString();
        DataOutputStream outToServer = new DataOutputStream (cSocket.getOutputStream());
        while (true)
        {
            msg = inFromUser.readLine();
            System.out.println(msg);
            if (msg.equals("exit"))
            {
                System.out.println("exit");
                break;
            }
            outToServer.writeBytes(cAddress + " said : " + msg + '\n'); //this line throws an exception the second time it runs
        }
        cSocket.close();
    }
}
```

I am new in java so I am missing something obvious I guess. Exception reads :

> Exception in thread "main"
>   java.net.SocketException: Software
>   caused connection abort: socket write
>   error
>           at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
>           at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:92)
>           at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:115)
>           at java.io.DataOutputStream.writeBytes(DataOutputStream.java:259)
>           at TCPclient.main(TCPClient.java:52) Java
>   Result: 1

Server :

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

class TCPServer {
   public static void main(String argv[]) throws Exception {
      String clientSentence;
      ServerSocket welcomeSocket = new ServerSocket(44444);
      while(true) {
         Socket connectionSocket = welcomeSocket.accept();
         BufferedReader inFromClient = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(connectionSocket.getInputStream( ) ) );
         clientSentence = inFromClient.readLine();
         System.out.println(clientSentence + "\n");
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2126607/official-reasons-for-software-caused-connection-abort-socket-write-error

Comment: Thanks - I think it must be something simpler in my case - the "server" always receives the first string I type and I get an exception on the second - it is not that I get mixed up my strings or anything

Comment: @dardana: It's very hard to know what's going on with no idea of what the server is.

Comment: Thanks for reading - posting the server

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but nevertheless: you should use `DataOutputStream` only if you intend to serialize Java types. If you just want a output streams to write bytes, just use the OutputStream returned by `cSocket.getOutputStream()`.

Comment: @leonbloy: That's not true.  That's what an ObjectOutputStream is for.  But you do note an absolutely critical error.  DataInput and OutputStream **MUST** be used symmetrically.  If you write with a DataOutputStream, you must read with a DataInputStream.  What @dardana is doing is writing using writeBytes and reading using readLine.  What you should be doing instead is using `PrintWriter.println(String)` to write a string and `BufferedReader.readLine()` to read a string.

Comment: I replaced all 
    ''DataInputStream with Print Writer - like
    PrintWriter outToServer = new PrintWriter(cSocket.getOutputStream());''
and
    outToServer.writeBytes(...);
with 
    outToServer.println(...);
but nothing is displayed in server (??)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your client creates one socket and writes over and over again to that one socket.  Your server, on the other hand, does this:

```
ServerSocket welcomeSocket = new ServerSocket(44444);
while(true) {
   Socket connectionSocket = welcomeSocket.accept();
```

That accepts the incoming connection, reads one line, and then abandons it (and I'm guessing on the socket's finalize when being garbage collected it closes the connection).  Then it waits for a new connection.

So to fix your immediate problem, try moving

```
    Socket connectionSocket = welcomeSocket.accept();
    BufferedReader inFromClient = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(connectionSocket.getInputStream( ) ) );
```

before the while loop.

Comment: Thanks indeed - I am a newbie and it shows :) I'll try what you say

Comment: That's right.  The server endpoint abandoned the connection and stopped reading from it.  Recall that a server socket has the ability to accept incoming connections from *multiple* client sockets.  Once you've accepted a connection through `accept`, however, the socket retrieved is persistent (through the magic of TCP/IP).  There is no need to reestablish the connection every time you want to send data down the line.

Answer (score 1):

How long do you wait between typing second line? It might have something to do with socket being idle.

Also with the server code like this you will see only first message. Try this:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

class TCPServer {
    public static void main(String argv[]) throws Exception {
        String clientSentence;
        ServerSocket welcomeSocket = new ServerSocket(44444);
        Socket connectionSocket = welcomeSocket.accept();
        BufferedReader inFromClient = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connectionSocket.getInputStream()));
        while (true) {
            clientSentence = inFromClient.readLine();
            System.out.println(clientSentence + "\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much - I will try your suggestions immediately - thanks

Comment: Works - thanks - it is not the socket being idle but the connection closing (???)

Comment: I tend to agree with Mark Peters: You simply drop all the references to the server socket after receiving first message. At some point socket will be closed and you will get the exception.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
while (true)
{
    if(inFromUser.readLine() != null)
    {        
        msg = inFromUser.readLine();

        System.out.println(msg);
        if (msg.equals("exit"))
        {
           System.out.println("exit");
           break;
        }

        outToServer.writeBytes(cAddress + " said : " + msg + "\n");
    }
}
```

Note the changes:

```
if(inFromUser.readLine() != null)
{
```

and

```
... "\n");
```

not

```
... '\n');
```

Give it a shot. It's probably too simple a solution, but it's something :)

Comment: Sending second line of every two lines and converting Character literal to String literal will not help the socket problem I am afraid.