# Sending Files Through Stream

Tags: java, stream, network-programming

Here is what I have right now.

Receiver:

```
public static void read(Socket socket, ObjectInputStream in) {
    try {
        String separator = in.readUTF();
        while (in.readByte() == -3) {
            String path = in.readUTF().replaceAll(separator, System.getProperty("file.separator"));
            File file = new File(new File(path).getParent());
            if (!file.exists()) {
                file.mkdirs();
            }
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(path);
            int b = 0;
            while ((b = in.readByte()) != -4) {
                fos.write(b);
            }
            fos.close();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Sender:

```
public static void send(String[] path) {
    Socket socket;
    try {
        socket = new Socket(ip, port);
        socket.setKeepAlive(true);
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        return;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return;
    }
    try {
        ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        out.writeUTF(Devbox.getSeparator());
        for (String s : path) {
            send(s, out);
            out.writeByte(-2);
        }
        out.close();
        socket.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private static void send(String path, ObjectOutputStream out) {
    File file = new File(path);
    if (file.isDirectory()) {
        File[] files = file.listFiles();
        for (File f : files) {
            send(path + f.getName(), out);
        }
    } else {
        try {
            out.writeByte(-3);
            out.writeUTF(path);
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
            int b = 0;
            while ((b = fis.read()) != -1) {
                out.writeByte(b);
            }
            fis.close();
            out.writeByte(-4);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

This is the error I get in the sender.

```
java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: socket write error
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:109)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:153)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.writeBlockHeader(ObjectOutputStream.java:1874)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.drain(ObjectOutputStream.java:1855)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.writeByte(ObjectOutputStream.java:1895)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeByte(ObjectOutputStream.java:760)
```

It points to

```
                out.writeByte(b);
```

It sends about 25 files successfully, then throws this error. The file it throws it on is different each time, but it is in the same range of about 5 files. The receiver stops after one specific file which is usually a couple before the file the sender stops on. It stops because in.readByte() == -3 is false. When it happens, I got numbers like -85 and 16. I tried it on another computer, since it said something about software, and it was the exact same. Does anyone know why this is happening? I've spent a day trying to figure it out, and gotten nowhere. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you guarantee that your input files do not contain the value -4 ? Otherwise, the receiver stops writing bytes to the output file (and maybe even closes the connection ?) while the sender is still writing data to the stream.

Comment: @AndreHolzner Yes, I can guarantee that is not the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2126607/official-reasons-for-software-caused-connection-abort-socket-write-error), I don't think anything else can be said beyond that, also I don't see anything in your code which will close the connection.

From OTN Discussion

> WinSock description: The error can occur when the local network system
>   aborts a connection. This would occur if WinSock aborts an established
>   connection after data retransmission fails (receiver never
>   acknowledges data sent on a datastream socket).
>
> TCP/IP scenario: A connection will timeout if the local system doesn't
>   receive an (ACK)nowledgement for data sent. It would also timeout if a
>   (FIN)ish TCP packet is not ACK'd (and even if the FIN is ACK'd, it
>   will eventually timeout if a FIN is not returned).
>
> It seems to happen more with WindowsXP and it seems also to be
>   possibly related to Windows firewall settings. In any case the salient
>   point is that the abort has originated inside the local machine.

Comment: If this is the case, is there any way to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Use a BufferedInputStream to read the FileInputStream in the send method.

```
BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
while ((b = bis.read()) != -1) {
    out.writeByte(b);
}
```

Also try a complementary BufferedOutputStream

```
BufferedInputStream bos = new FileOutputStream(path);
int b = 0;
while ((b = in.readByte()) != -4) {
    bos.write(b);
}
```

In addition, you need to flush out your connections when the file finishes transfer.

```
out.flush;
```

Comment: It does the same thing, it didn't help.

Comment: You might need a complementing BufferedOutputStream on the receiver's read method.