# How to solve "Connection reset by peer: socket write error"?

Tags: java, servlets, socketexception

When I am reading the file content from server it returns the following error message:

```
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalOutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(InternalOutputBuffer.java:215)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.flushBuffer(ByteChunk.java:462)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.append(ByteChunk.java:366)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalOutputBuffer$OutputStreamOutputBuffer.doWrite(InternalOutputBuffer.java:240)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.filters.ChunkedOutputFilter.doWrite(ChunkedOutputFilter.java:119)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractOutputBuffer.doWrite(AbstractOutputBuffer.java:192)
at org.apache.coyote.Response.doWrite(Response.java:504)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:383)
... 28 more
```

and my servlet program is

```
 response.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
 response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment;filename="+filename);
 FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(new File(filepath));
 ServletOutputStream output=response.getOutputStream();
 byte[] outputByte=new byte[4096];
 while(in.read(outputByte,0,4096)!=-1){
     output.write(outputByte,0,4096);//error indicates in this line
 }
 in.close();
 output.flush();
 output.close();
```

How to solve this issue?

Comment: What is the client and how does it read the response if it is written by you?

Comment: Post the stack trace which indicates the error in line output.write(). Like Serge requested, please also post the client code if applicable.

Comment: I made a request to this servlet by jquery ajax function.

Comment: I download a file in onclick() of div.

Comment: @BabuR have you found a solution to this problem? I am struggling with the same problem while trying to transfer video through a servlet.

Comment: Read this for the complete explanation and possible resolution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30538640/javax-net-ssl-sslexception-read-error-ssl-0x9524b800-i-o-error-during-system?lq=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Official reasons for "Software caused connection abort: socket write error"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2126607/official-reasons-for-software-caused-connection-abort-socket-write-error)

Answer (score 14):

I've got the same exception and in my case the problem was in a renegotiation procecess. In fact my client closed a connection when the server tried to change a cipher suite. After digging it appears that in the jdk 1.6 update 22 [renegotiation process is disabled by default](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/tlsreadme2-176330.html). If your security constraints can effort this, try to enable the unsecure renegotiation by setting the `sun.security.ssl.allowUnsafeRenegotiation` system property to `true`. Here is some information about the process:

> Session renegotiation is a mechanism within the SSL protocol that
>   allows the client or the server to trigger a new SSL handshake during
>   an ongoing SSL communication. Renegotiation was initially designed as
>   a mechanism to increase the security of an ongoing SSL channel, by
>   triggering the renewal of the crypto keys used to secure that channel.
>   However, this security measure isn't needed with modern cryptographic
>   algorithms. Additionally, renegotiation can be used by a server to
>   request a client certificate (in order to perform client
>   authentication) when the client tries to access specific, protected
>   resources on the server.

Additionally there is the [excellent post](http://jce.iaik.tugraz.at/sic/Products/Communication-Messaging-Security/iSaSiLk/documentation/Secure-Renegotiation) about this issue in details and written in (IMHO) understandable language.

Answer (score 3):

The socket has been closed by the client (browser).

A bug in your code:

```
byte[] outputByte=new byte[4096];
while(in.read(outputByte,0,4096)!=-1){
   output.write(outputByte,0,4096);
}
```

The last packet read, then write may have a length < 4096, so I suggest:

```
byte[] outputByte=new byte[4096];
int len;
while(( len = in.read(outputByte, 0, 4096 )) > 0 ) {
   output.write( outputByte, 0, len );
}
```

It's not your question, but it's my answer... ;-)

Comment: While you are right about writing the correct length of bytes to the stream, this should not cause a 'Connection reset by peer' error. The client should just see some junk after the right data.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried with your code. but it shows java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException

Comment: I solved the indexoutofbounds pbm. but the same problem what i asked is remain:\

Comment: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:388)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.flushBuffer(ByteChunk.java:462)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.append(ByteChunk.java:366)
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.writeBytes(OutputBuffer.java:413)
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.write(OutputBuffer.java:401)
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.write(CoyoteOutputStream.java:91)

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to 'solve' it is to close the connection and forget about the client. The client has closed the connection while you where still writing to it, so he doesn't want to know you, so that's it, isn't it?

Comment: can you pls tell me how to close the connection?

Comment: @BabuR Close the output stream.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your problem may be arising at

`while(in.read(outputByte,0,4096)!=-1){`

where it might go into an infinite loop for not advancing the offset (which is 0 always in the call).  Try

`while(in.read(outputByte)!=-1){`

which will by default try to read upto outputByte.length into the `byte[]`. This way you dont have to worry about the offset. See [FileInputStrem's read method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html#read%28byte%5B%5D%29)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with small difference:

> Exception was raised at the moment of flushing

It is a different [stackoverflow issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36979706/setting-content-encoding-to-gzip-or-deflate-causes-java-net-socketexception-c/). The brief explanation was a wrong response header setting:

response.setHeader("Content-Encoding", "gzip");

despite uncompressed response data content.

So the the connection was closed by the browser.