# Cant access to FTP using Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, remote-access

I am using the Remote System software on Eclipse. I can successfully log in to my FTP account but when I try to view the directories, I get the following message:

> Message: Operation failed due to network I/O error
>   'java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write
>   error'

Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: Did you tried to access FTP via any other FTP client, to be sure its an Eclipse problem?

Comment: @Samuel yes, I have tried it with FileZilla and it works.

Comment: What is your eclipse version? What is your jdk version?

Comment: @Samuel I use Eclipse Mars Release (4.5.0) and Java version 8 & update 45

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there could be some negotiation issue.

Try [following solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17656389/524743):

> I've got the same exception and in my case the problem was in a
>   renegotiation procecess. In fact my client closed a connection when
>   the server tried to change a cipher suite. After digging it appears
>   that in the jdk 1.6 update 22 renegotiation process is disabled by
>   default. If your security constraints can effort this, try to enable
>   the unsecure renegotiation by setting the
>   sun.security.ssl.allowUnsafeRenegotiation system property to true.

---

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/overview/tlsreadme2-176330.html

> Setting the System Properties/Mode Configuration The various modes are
>   set using the corresponding system properties, which must be set
>   before the SunJSSE library is initialized. There are several ways to
>   set these properties:
>
> From the command line:
>
> % java -Dsun.security.ssl.allowUnsafeRenegotiation=true Main Within
>   the application:
>
> java.lang.System.setProperty("sun.security.ssl.allowUnsafeRenegotiation",
>   true); In the Java Deployment environment (Plug-In/Web Start), there
>   are several ways to set the system properties. (See Java Web App and
>   Next Generation Web Browser Plugin for more information.)
>
> Use the Java Control Panel to set the Runtime Environment Property on
>   a local/per-VM basis. This creates a local deployment.properties file.
>   Deployers can also distribute a enterprise-wide deployment.properties
>   file by using the deployment.config mechanism. (See Deployment
>   Configuration File and Properties.)
>
> To set a property for a specific applet, use the HTML subtag 
>   "java_arguments" within the  tag. (See Java Arguments.)
>
> To set the property in a specific Java Web Start application or applet
>   using the new Plugin2 (6u10+), use the JNLP "property" sub-element of
>   the "resources" element. (See Resources Element.)

Comment: Thanks but where or how do I change this property?