# Single RMI clients marshalling exception

Tags: client, marshalling, rmi

I am facing a very strange problem.

I am using my application with RMI for 8 month in production but since a new (big) update I dont know what is wrong.

It is a server where 3 clients connect.

And when I am using only client with a certain method I can not find anything wrong especially because all other clients work perfectly.

Is there maybe with RMI any local "cache" which should be deleted otherwise I can't tell.

Here is the output of the client's console:

```
C:\Users\Claudia\Desktop>java -jar CLIENT_erp_auer_client_v0_8ASASADSD.jar
java.rmi.MarshalException: error marshalling arguments; nested exception is:
        java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: socket write error
        at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invokeRemoteMethod(Unknown Sou
rce)
        at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at $Proxy7.update(Unknown Source)
        at client.entity_types.LieferscheinpositionService.aendereLieferscheinposition(
LieferscheinpositionService.java:60)
        at client.lieferscheinverwaltung.TreeTableNEULieferschein.addLieferscheinpositi
onen(TreeTableNEULieferschein.java:912)
        at client.lieferscheinverwaltung.TreeTableNEULieferschein.<init>(TreeTableNEULi
eferschein.java:204)
        at client.lieferscheinverwaltung.LieferscheinErstellung.getTreeTableNeuLiefersc
hein(LieferscheinErstellung.java:916)
        at client.lieferscheinverwaltung.LieferscheinErstellung.<init>(LieferscheinErst
ellung.java:773)
        at client.lieferscheinverwaltung.LieferscheinManagement.openLieferschein(Liefer
scheinManagement.java:1055)
        at client.lieferscheinverwaltung.LieferscheinManagement$9.mouseClicked(Liefersc
```

Thank you.

Comment: There is no RMI cache. This is a network problem. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7747693/207421).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Official reasons for "Software caused connection abort: socket write error"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2126607/official-reasons-for-software-caused-connection-abort-socket-write-error)

Comment: Ok I figured now out that step 2. - and I can ping other hosts in the same subnet and the server from the mentioned not working client.
But in the other direction I can not ping this one client from both other clients. What could that be? Worked some days before fine...

Comment: Network problem; new question; and off topic. Try serverfault.