# How to solve java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: socket write error exception

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, network-programming, socketexception

I have this error
 SEVERE: `SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [/firstjsp] threw exception [ClientAbortException:  java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: socket write error] with root cause`
when I run my application sometimes .

The error messages are

```
java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: socket write error
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalOutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(InternalOutputBuffer.java:216)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.flushBuffer(ByteChunk.java:460)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.append(ByteChunk.java:368)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalOutputBuffer$OutputStreamOutputBuffer.doWrite(InternalOutputBuffer.java:241)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.filters.ChunkedOutputFilter.doWrite(ChunkedOutputFilter.java:119)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractOutputBuffer.doWrite(AbstractOutputBuffer.java:192)
at org.apache.coyote.Response.doWrite(Response.java:533)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:373)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.append(ByteChunk.java:373)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.writeBytes(OutputBuffer.java:403)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.write(OutputBuffer.java:391)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.write(CoyoteOutputStream.java:91)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.write(CoyoteOutputStream.java:84)
at ChartDirector.GetSessionImage.a(SourceFile:90)
at ChartDirector.WebChartViewer.streamChart(SourceFile:301)
at org.apache.jsp.AutomaticAlarm_jsp._jspService(AutomaticAlarm_jsp.java:157)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:928)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:987)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:539)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:298)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

My java code is:

```js
 public Connection getConnection() {


   String connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:49184;databaseName=Alarm;user=sa;password=Controls@#$%";


   try {
     Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
     con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);
   } catch (Exception e) {
     System.out.println(" \nException in getConnection() " + e);
   }
   return con;

 }

 public void closeConnection(Statement stmt, ResultSet rs, Connection con) {
   try {
     if (stmt != null) {
       stmt.close();
     }
     if (rs != null) {
       rs.close();
     }
     if (con != null) {
       con.close();
     }

   } catch (Exception e) {
     System.out.println("\nexception in closeConnection( Statement stmt, ResultSet rs, Connection con)  " + e);
   }

 }
   

 public int get_Count1()

 {

   {



     try {
       con = getConnection();

       stmt = con.createStatement();

       String sql = " SELECT system_name, COUNT(distinct arrival_time) AS c FROM i2alarmlog WHERE Ack_status = 0 AND Direction='CAME' AND arrival_time between '2014-01-22 17:56:41.000' and '2014-01-24 17:56:41.000' and system_name in('I2-tciu database','i2-vcs logging','Indus1 Vacuum','Indus2 TCIU','Indus2 Vacuum','Septum_SIP2','TL3 Vacuum') GROUP BY system_name UNION ALL select 'TotalSum' as TotalSum,sum(s.c) as TotalValue from (SELECT system_name, COUNT(distinct arrival_time) AS c FROM i2alarmlog WHERE Ack_status = 0 AND Direction='CAME' and arrival_time between '2014-01-22 17:56:41.000' and '2014-01-24 17:56:41.000' AND system_name in('I2-tciu database','i2-vcs logging','Indus1 Vacuum','Indus2 TCIU','Indus2 Vacuum','Septum_SIP2','TL3 Vacuum') GROUP BY system_name ) s";


       stmt.executeQuery(sql);
       rs = stmt.getResultSet();



       while (rs.next()) {
         t1 = (rs.getInt(2));


       }

     } catch (Exception e) {
       System.out.println("\nException " + e);

     } finally {
       closeConnection(stmt, rs, con);
     }

   }



   System.out.println(t1);

   return t1;

 }
```

How to resolve it.
I have used Jsp for display.I have used chartdirector for displaying charts as:-

```js
<% @page import = "ChartDirector.*" %>
  <%
  // The data for the line chart

  double[] data1 = ab.total();

// The labels for the line chart
String[] labels = {
  "VACUUM", "RSS", "MPS", "RF", "BLFE", "ORBIT", "LCW", "TCS", "INTERLOCK", "BDS", "MSIS", "MICROTON", "POWER CONDITIONER", "DATABASE"
};

XYChart c = new XYChart(1000, 650);
c.setPlotArea(90, 60, 750, 430);

c.xAxis().setLabels(labels);
c.xAxis().setTitle("System_Name", "Arial Bold", 12);
c.xAxis().setLabelStyle("Arial Bold", 10).setFontAngle(45);

c.addBarLayer3(data1).setBorderColor(Chart.Transparent, Chart.softLighting(Chart.Left));

BarLayer layer = c.addBarLayer2(Chart.Stack, 10);
layer.setAggregateLabelStyle();
layer.addDataSet(data1, 10, "Arial Bold Italic");
layer.setBorderColor(Chart.Transparent, Chart.softLighting(Chart.Top));

c.xAxis().setColors(Chart.Transparent);
c.yAxis().setColors(Chart.Transparent);


c.yAxis().setTitle("Alarm_Count", "Arial Bold", 12);

c.yAxis().setLabelStyle("Arial Bold", 10);
c.yAxis().setLinearScale(0.0, ab.max_Count());
c.yAxis().setLabelStep(2);
c.yAxis().setMargin(7);
c.xAxis().setWidth(2);
c.yAxis().setWidth(2);


try {
  // stream the chart to the browser and terminate immediately
  out.clear();
  if (WebChartViewer.streamChart(response, c.makeChart2(Chart.PNG)))
    return;
} catch (IllegalStateException e) {
  // Some very old servers may not support streaming. So we are forced to redirect
  // to the browser to use the traditional method.
  response.sendRedirect(response.encodeRedirectURL("getchart.jsp?" +
    c.makeSession(request, "chart")));
  return;
}


%>
```

Moreover,the chart is updated randomly.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Official reasons for "Software caused connection abort: socket write error"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2126607/official-reasons-for-software-caused-connection-abort-socket-write-error)

Comment: Why are you streaming the PNG image using a JSP page? I suggest to change this into a servlet or whatever MVC framework you use (e.g. Controller in SpringMVC).
On line #1 of your JSP you have a newline, so the output from the JSP already contains a newline. Then you call 'out.clear()', probably to fix the newline?
I suggest you either use JSP to generate HTML and use c.makeSession(), or to use servlet/controller to stream the chart.