# Getting SocketException Every time

Tags: java, eclipse, automation

Getting this exception every time, when I run suite or individual java file:

```
java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: socket write error
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.drain(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.setBlockDataMode(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.remote.strprotocol.SerializedMessageSender.sendMessage(SerializedMessageSender.java:24)
    at org.testng.remote.strprotocol.MessageHub.sendMessage(MessageHub.java:44)
    at org.testng.remote.strprotocol.RemoteTestListener.onTestStart(RemoteTestListener.java:49)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.runTestListeners(Invoker.java:1904)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.runTestListeners(Invoker.java:1879)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:685)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:901)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1231)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.access$000(SuiteRunner.java:37)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner$SuiteWorker.run(SuiteRunner.java:368)
    at org.testng.internal.thread.ThreadUtil$2.call(ThreadUtil.java:64)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Its running java file, no problem with its working but still its throwing this exception

Comment: Could u plz post ur java program which is running fine but still throwing this exception.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2126607/official-reasons-for-software-caused-connection-abort-socket-write-error
Look into this link.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an issue with TestNG, Eclipse versions:

More info on github issue page: https://github.com/cbeust/testng-eclipse/issues/91

TestNG 6.9 version has issue with older eclipse versions. Uninstall existing testng

> Uninstall and install again from the update site:
>   http://beust.com/eclipse-previous (which points to 6.8.6)

or use latest Eclipse (Mars) version along with TestNG 6.9 and JDK 1.7/1.8.