# TestNG : java.net.socketException

Tags: java, sockets, testng

i'm trying to run TestNG tests, but i'm getting the following exception. What might be the reason? How do i fix this? In this stack overflow also one has given the solution. But that is not working in my case. Please suggest me. Thanks in advance.

```
Sep 03, 2015 7:10:00 AM com.google.appengine.api.datastore.dev.LocalDatastoreService init
INFO: Local Datastore initialized: 
    Type: High Replication
    Storage:`enter code here` In-memory
java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: socket write error
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:113)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:159)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.drain(ObjectOutputStream.java:1876)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.setBlockDataMode(ObjectOutputStream.java:1785)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNonProxyDesc(ObjectOutputStream.java:1285)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeClassDesc(ObjectOutputStream.java:1230)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1426)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeFatalException(ObjectOutputStream.java:1576)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:350)
    at org.testng.remote.strprotocol.SerializedMessageSender.sendMessage(SerializedMessageSender.java:25)
    at org.testng.remote.strprotocol.MessageHub.sendMessage(MessageHub.java:44)
    at org.testng.remote.strprotocol.RemoteTestListener.onTestSuccess(RemoteTestListener.java:92)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.runTestListeners(Invoker.java:1899)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.runTestListeners(Invoker.java:1879)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:778)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:901)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1231)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1198)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1123)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1031)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:111)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:204)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:175)
```

Comment: Please refer the below link to get answer

[**connection-abort-socket-write-error**][1]


  


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2126607/official-reasons-for-software-caused-connection-abort-socket-write-error

Comment: Please refer the below link to get answer[**connection-abort-socket-write-error**][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2126607/official-reasons-for-software-caused-connection-abort-socket-write-error

Comment: It's a known issue: [SocketException: Software caused connection abort #91](https://github.com/cbeust/testng-eclipse/issues/91)