# Java swing client server issue

Tags: java, sockets, client-server, objectinputstream, objectoutputstream

**What I'm trying to do**

A client/server application:
The client opens a GUI with a button "Read". 
Clicking it it will open a new frame with some articles to read. At this stage a short `String`.

**Abstract:**

- After you start both server and client , the Client will see the frame with a button.
- As a response, I want the server to send me specific/different things depending on what Operation I click.

**What I tried**

At this current stage of development I'm stuck with this error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: socket write error
```

**This is the server-class:**

```
public class StartServer {


    public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {

        @
        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(9999);
        System.out.println("Server started");


        while (true) {

            List<String> receive = new ArrayList<String>();

            // Wait for client to connect
            Socket aNewClientSocket = serverSocket.accept();

            System.out.println("Server-Client connexion established!!");

            ObjectInputStream toReceiveFromClient = new ObjectInputStream(aNewClientSocket.getInputStream());
            receive = (List<String>) toReceiveFromClient.readObject();

            System.out.println(aNewClientSocket.getLocalPort());
            System.out.println(aNewClientSocket.getInetAddress());

            switch (receive.get(0)) {
            case "Reader button click":
                List<Object> toSend = new ArrayList<Object>();
                Article a=new Article();
                a.setTitle("New Title");
                toSend.add(a);
                ObjectOutputStream objectWayToSend = new ObjectOutputStream(aNewClientSocket.getOutputStream());
                objectWayToSend.writeObject(toSend);
                objectWayToSend.flush();


            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Bad request from client!!");
            }
```

**The clients relevant method:**

```
    public void sendToServer(List<String> toSend) throws UnknownHostException, IOException {
        try {


        Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 9999);
        ObjectOutputStream objectWayToSend = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

        objectWayToSend.writeObject(toSend);
        objectWayToSend.flush();

        objectWayToSend.close();

        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "The server is offline or connection can't be establish!");
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<Object> receiveFromServer() throws UnknownHostException, IOException {
        List<Object> receive = new ArrayList<Object>();
        try {

            Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 9999);
        ObjectInputStream objectToGet = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

        receive=(List<Object>) objectToGet.readObject();



        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "The server is offline or connection can't be establish!");
        }
        return receive;
```

**The referenced button in the GUI**

```
    btnCiteste = new JButton("Read");
            btnCiteste.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                    List<String> toSend = new ArrayList<String>();
                    toSend.add("Read");
                    try {
                        sendToServer(toSend);
                        List<Object> received= receiveFromServer();
                        //new ArticoleReaderFrame ();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You close the `OutputStream` in the client after you finished sending but before you started receiving. That's the cause of your problem, since closing the `OutputStream` also closes the underlying Socket.

Referencing [Official reasons for “Software caused connection abort: socket write error”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2126607/official-reasons-for-software-caused-connection-abort-socket-write-error)

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Now it works but it has a problem. After I press the button the application freeze. Is there something bag at my server side?

Comment: I'd like you to ask a second question and link it here to keep the content separated.

Comment: @TufisiRadu feel free to read up on [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)