# getting error : "Network error : Software caused connection abort" in AWS SFTP

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Yesterday I have created instance in aws server, which was working yestrday, but when I today start to connect with `SFTP`, I am getting error `Network error : Software caused connection abort`, also same error getting in `putty`, I am new in aws, so I don't have much knowledge of it, I read some doc of aws but it didn't help me, can anyone please help why this error getting ? As per my think, it because of ip address change of my internet, may be this can be the issue, but I don't know how to resolve this issue, can anyone please help me?

Comment: Have to changed the rights for any folder like tmp??

Comment: No i didn't change anything yet

Comment: Please check this: https://superuser.com/questions/294824/putty-network-error-software-caused-connection-abort

Comment: Can you telnet to your host's IP address on port 22 (assuming you are using default port)? The command to issue will be something like `telnet public-ip-address 22` (eg `telnet 123.123.123.123 22`). If you can, you know your network connection is OK. Also, please share details of the security group you have on your EC2 instance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Official reasons for "Software caused connection abort: socket write error"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2126607/official-reasons-for-software-caused-connection-abort-socket-write-error)