# Software caused connection abort: socket write error for KerberosRestTemplate (spring-security-kerberos-client)

Tags: java, spring-security

Hello I am using KerberosRestTemplate (spring-security-kerberos-client)  in order to execute Druid Query through POST Method call.  I am getting "Software caused connection abort: socket write error".  The following is the code snippet I am using to make the post call. Has anyone ran into this sort of issue. I would really appreciate your help.

```
 public InputStream callRestUrlIP(final String url, final String userId, final String json) {
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<>(json, headers);
    KerberosRestTemplate kerberosRestTemplate = new KerberosRestTemplate(this.keyTabLocation, this.principal);
    ((HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory)kerberosRestTemplate.getRequestFactory()).setReadTimeout(40000);
    ((HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory)kerberosRestTemplate.getRequestFactory()).setConnectTimeout(40000);
    ResponseEntity<Resource> responseEntity = kerberosRestTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST,request, Resource.class);
    responseEntity.getHeaders().add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip");
    responseEntity.getHeaders().add("Content-Type", "application/json");
    InputStream responseInputStream;
    try {
        responseInputStream = responseEntity.getBody().getInputStream();
        responseInputStream.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    return responseInputStream;
}
```

The following code works without using KerberosRestTemplate:

```
public InputStream callRestUrlIP(final String url, final String userId, final String json) {
        keyTabLocation = keyTabLocation.substring("file://".length());
        System.out.println(String.format("Calling KerberosHttpClient %s %s %s", this.principal, this.keyTabLocation, url));
        Configuration config = new Configuration() {
            @SuppressWarnings("serial")
            @Override
            public AppConfigurationEntry[] getAppConfigurationEntry(String name) {
                return new AppConfigurationEntry[]{new AppConfigurationEntry("com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule",
                        AppConfigurationEntry.LoginModuleControlFlag.REQUIRED, new HashMap<String, Object>() {
                    {
                        put("useTicketCache", "false");
                        put("useKeyTab", "true");
                        put("keyTab", keyTabLocation);
                        //Krb5 in GSS API needs to be refreshed so it does not throw the error
                        //Specified version of key is not available
                        put("refreshKrb5Config", "true");
                        put("principal", principal);
                        put("storeKey", "true");
                        put("doNotPrompt", "true");
                        put("isInitiator", "true");
                        put("debug", "true");
                    }
                })};
            }
        };
        Set<Principal> princ = new HashSet<Principal>(1);
        princ.add(new KerberosPrincipal(userId));
        Subject sub = new Subject(false, princ, new HashSet<Object>(), new HashSet<Object>());
        try {
            LoginContext lc = new LoginContext("", sub, null, config);
            lc.login();
            Subject serviceSubject = lc.getSubject();
            return Subject.doAs(serviceSubject, new PrivilegedAction<InputStream>() {
                List<DruidGroupByResponse> httpResponse = null;

                @Override
                public InputStream run() {
                    try {
                        Instant start = Instant.now();

                        URL url_ = new URL(url);

                        AuthenticatedURL.Token token = new AuthenticatedURL.Token();

                        java.net.HttpURLConnection connection = new AuthenticatedURL().openConnection(url_, token);

                        connection = new AuthenticatedURL().openConnection(url_, token);

                        connection.setConnectTimeout(connectTimeout);
                        connection.setReadTimeout(readTimeout);
                        connection.setDoOutput(true);
                        connection.setDoInput(true);
                        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
                        connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
                        connection.connect();
                        byte[] outputInBytes = json.getBytes("UTF-8");
                        OutputStream os = connection.getOutputStream();
                        os.write(outputInBytes);
                        os.close();

                        int HttpResult = connection.getResponseCode();
                        log.info("Response code call url " + url + " : " + HttpResult);

                        Instant endTillResponseCode = Instant.now();
                        log.info("Time took to execute rest call : " + Duration.between(start, endTillResponseCode).toMillis());

                        if (HttpResult == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                            log.info("Response code success to call url " + url);
                            // InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(connection.getOutputStream())
                            JavaType type = ObjectMapperFactory.getInstance().getTypeFactory().constructCollectionType(List.class, DruidGroupByResponse.class);
                            InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
                            //List<DruidResponse> httpResponse = mapper.readValue(connection.getInputStream(), type);
                            Instant endTillResponseObj = Instant.now();
                            log.info("Time took to execute rest call with objs in memeory : " + Duration.between(start, endTillResponseObj).toMillis());
                            return is;
                        } else {
                            log.info("Response code failue to call url " + url + " : " + connection.getResponseMessage());
                        }


                    } catch (IOException | AuthenticationException ioe) {
                        ioe.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    return null;
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception le) {
            le.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
}
```

The following post call works for the same URL and I am getting the List as the response:

```
public List<DruidGroupByResponse> callRestUrl(final String url, final String userId, final String json)
    {
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<>(json, headers);
        KerberosRestTemplate kerberosRestTemplate = new KerberosRestTemplate(this.keyTabLocation, this.principal);
        List<DruidGroupByResponse> obj = kerberosRestTemplate.postForObject(url,request, List.class);
        return obj;
    }
```

Error Stack:

```
2019-02-28 14:04:38.581  INFO 14108 --- [nio-8904-exec-5] o.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec   : I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request to {}->URL: Software caused connection abort: socket write error
2019-02-28 14:04:38.581  INFO 14108 --- [nio-8904-exec-5] o.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec   : Retrying request to {}->URL
2019-02-28 14:04:38.598  INFO 14108 --- [nio-8904-exec-5] o.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec   : I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request to {}->URL: Software caused connection abort: socket write error
2019-02-28 14:04:38.599  INFO 14108 --- [nio-8904-exec-5] o.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec   : Retrying request to {}->URL
2019-02-28 14:04:38.619 ERROR 14108 --- [nio-8904-exec-5] c.r.r.r.r.c.p.GeneralExceptionMapper     : Error running rest call; nested exception is org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request for "URL": Software caused connection abort: recv failed; nested exception is java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed

    org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Error running rest call; nested exception is org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request for "": Software caused connection abort: recv failed; nested exception is java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed
        at org.springframework.security.kerberos.client.KerberosRestTemplate.doExecute(KerberosRestTemplate.java:196)
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:621)
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:539)
        at com.rbc.rbccs.r0c0.reportingrest.service.druid.KerberosHttpClient.callRestUrlIP(KerberosHttpClient.java:349)
        at com.rbc.rbccs.r0c0.reportingrest.service.druid.druidry.DruidClient.getQueryResponse(DruidClient.java:55)
        at com.rbc.rbccs.r0c0.reportingrest.service.dimension.executor.QueryExecutor.getQueryResponse(QueryExecutor.java:33)
        at com.rbc.rbccs.r0c0.reportingrest.service.dimension.executor.QueryExecutor.getQueryResponseFromUI(QueryExecutor.java:38)
        at com.rbc.rbccs.r0c0.reportingrest.service.DimensionService.getQueryResponse(DimensionService.java:71)
        at com.rbc.rbccs.r0c0.reportingrest.rest.query.DimensionController.getQueryDimensions(DimensionController.java:48)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:144)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:161)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:160)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:99)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:389)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:347)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:102)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:326)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:305)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1154)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:473)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:427)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:388)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:341)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:228)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.filter.ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.java:55)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.AbstractRequestLoggingFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractRequestLoggingFilter.java:244)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:111)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
        at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
        at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
        at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:215)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:96)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
        at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:66)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:347)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:263)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:103)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:800)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:800)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1471)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request for " ": Software caused connection abort: recv failed; nested exception is java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:674)
        at org.springframework.security.kerberos.client.KerberosRestTemplate.doExecuteSubject(KerberosRestTemplate.java:202)
        at org.springframework.security.kerberos.client.KerberosRestTemplate.access$100(KerberosRestTemplate.java:67)
        at org.springframework.security.kerberos.client.KerberosRestTemplate$1.run(KerberosRestTemplate.java:191)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
        at org.springframework.security.kerberos.client.KerberosRestTemplate.doExecute(KerberosRestTemplate.java:187)
        ... 123 common frames omitted
    Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:170)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
        at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.streamRead(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:137)
        at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.fillBuffer(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:153)
        at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.readLine(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:282)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:138)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:56)
        at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:259)
        at org.apache.http.impl.DefaultBHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultBHttpClientConnection.java:163)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.CPoolProxy.receiveResponseHeader(CPoolProxy.java:165)
        at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:273)
        at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:125)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:272)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:185)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56)
        at org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(HttpComponentsClientHttpRequest.java:89)
        at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:48)
        at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:53)
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:660)
        ... 129 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Show the stacktrace of the original Exception. That is a pretty generic message discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2126607/1531971